# The meaning of "on"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-meaning

What does "on" mean in the examples? I also have another question. In the sentence one, does "*on*" make an idiom with "*later*" or do we use "*on*" here because of the "*the show*" coming after "on"?

> 1- The episode introduced the character Akira, who has appeared many
>   times later ***on*** the show.
>
> 2- I also appeared ***on*** the show.
>
> 3- Previously ***on*** Prison Break ... (a tv-series)

Answer (score 1):

"On" is one of those words with many nuances. Look at all of the various definitions here https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/on - 5c and 6b carry the meanings you have in mind. Grammatically, it's a preposition, as you noted. Also, as you noted, "on" is generally the word I would use with US English with reference to a play, movie, or show - either someone participating as an actor, or something happening as part of the show.

In the first sentence, I would consider "the show" to be idiomatic, meaning "the series."

Comment: Thanks, could you answer my other question too? " In the sentence one, does "on" make an idiom with "later" or do we use "on" here because of the "the show" coming after "on"?"

Comment: Edited. I believe "the show" is the idiom rather than "later on".